# How to find links and modify an Html using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Starting from an Html input like this:

```
<p>
<a href="http://www.foo.com">this if foo</a>
<a href="http://www.bar.com">this if bar</a>
</p>
```

using BeautifulSoup, i would like to change this Html in:

```
<p>
<a href="http://www.foo.com">this if foo[1]</a>
<a href="http://www.bar.com">this if bar[2]</a>
</p>
```

saving parsed links in a dictionary with a result like this:

```
links_dict = {"1":"http://www.foo.com","2":"http://www.bar.com"}
```

Is it possible to do this using BeautifulSoup? Any valid alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be easy in Beautiful Soup.

Something like:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from BeautifulSoup import Tag

count = 1
links_dict = {}
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
for link_tag in soup.findAll('a'):
  if link_tag['href'] and len(link_tag['href']) > 0:
    links_dict[count]  = link_tag['href']  
    newTag = Tag(soup, "a", link_tag.attrs)
    newTag.insert(0, ''.join([''.join(link_tag.contents), "[%s]" % str(count)]))
    link_tag.replaceWith(newTag)
    count += 1
```

Result of executing this on your text:

```
>>> soup
<p>
  <a href="http://www.foo.com">this if foo[1]</a>
  <a href="http://www.bar.com">this if bar[2]</a>
</p>

>>> links_dict
{1: u'http://www.foo.com', 2: u'http://www.bar.com'}
```

The only problem I can foresee with this solution is if your link text contains subtags; then you couldn't do `''.join(link_tag.contents)`; instead you would need to navigate to the rightmost text element.

Comment: @danben +1 for the effort. Actually this is like the code i made before asking the question. It does not work because you end up with something like <a href="http://www.foo.com[1]">this if foo</a> and this is not what i want.

Comment: @danben do you think is it possible to change the node's content without recreating a new tag?

Comment: I was not able to do that, and the documentation suggests that there is not.  Why is creating a new Tag undesirable?

Comment: @Danben uhm, because i could have other attributes besides href; a rel="nofollow" for example.Please, have a look to this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904542/is-it-possibile-to-modify-a-link-value-with-beautifulsoup-without-recreating-the

Comment: @Danben Ok i found it; i replaced newTag = Tag(soup, "a", [("href", link_tag['href'])])
  with  newTag = Tag(soup, "a", link_tag.attrs).Thanks!Please update your code.

Comment: For the record, with 3.08 you can avoid Tag class and update directly link_tag.string. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904542/is-it-possibile-to-modify-a-link-value-with-beautifulsoup-without-recreating-the